# Extract rows corresponds to a another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have two data frames as follow

```
> df1 <- data.frame(f1=c(1,2,3, 2), f2 = c(10, 20, 30, 10), f3=c("A", "B", "B", "A") )
> df1
  f1 f2 f3
1  1 10  A
2  2 20  B
3  3 30  B
4  2 10  A
> 
> df2 <- data.frame(f1=c(1,3), f2 = c(10, 30) )
> df2
  f1 f2
1  1 10
2  3 30
```

The dataframe df2 is a subset dataframe of df1. Now I want to extract the rows in df1 corresponds to df2, including the column f3. Any suggestion?

Comment: `merge(df1, df2)`

Comment: alistaire's answer is correct.

Comment: `merge(df1,df2, "<keyhere>", all.x=T`